# Convert a CSV to a Parquet in a Notebook

Tags: pyspark, pipeline, azure-synapse

I'm just stepping into the data world and have been asked to create a custom project where I need to convert a CSV to a parquet using a Notebook (PySpark). I've put this together so far, which seems to run without errors but there's nothing in my Parquet folder in ADLS.

```py
def convert_csv_to_parquet(input_file_path, output_file_path):
    # Read CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path)

    # Convert Pandas DataFrame to PyArrow Table
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

    # Write PyArrow Table to Parquet file
    pq.write_table(table, output_file_path)

    # Open the Parquet file
    table = pq.read_table(output_file_path)

    # Convert the table to a Pandas DataFrame
    df = table.to_pandas()

    # Print the DataFrame
    print(df.head(100))


input_file_path = 'abfss://mycontainer@mygen2acc.dfs.core.windows.net/MySQL_Project-Table_Courses.csv'
output_file_path = 'abfss://mycontainer@mygen2acc.dfs.core.windows.net/Parquet'

convert_csv_to_parquet(input_file_path, output_file_path)
```

Comment: are you intentionally using Pandas? Or do you think Pandas are PySpark? They are very different. Although PySpark provides inter-operability with Pandas, a pandas DataFrame is very different from PySpark/Spark DataFrame.

Comment: Ah I didn't know properly tbh, thanks for the shout!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas and PySpark are very different. Although PySpark provides inter-operability with Pandas, a pandas DataFrame is very different from PySpark/Spark DataFrame.

Understand the differences between Pandas and PySpark before you write any code.

---

There are two parts to your problem. First is understand how to read/write to/from csv and parquet files, which reside on your laptop's hard disk. Second is how to use ADSL instead of local hard disk.

##### For first part:

See the examples that come with [PySpark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html). E.g.

- [how to read from csv into a DataFrame](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/examples/src/main/python/sql/datasource.py#L260)
- [how to write a DataFrame to parquet](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/examples/src/main/python/sql/datasource.py#L164).

Also see the PySpark SQL API docs (PySpark SQL API is a python API, not SQL). E.g.

- [read/write csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv)
- [read/write parquet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet.html)

##### For second part:

When working with a cloud storage as underlying storage (ADLS, S3, ...), you need to:

1. Prefix all your paths with appropriate scheme e.g. `s3a`, `abfss`, ...
2. Install appropriate hadoop extension/library (that corresponds-to/supports the scheme) in your pyspark env. PySpark will use this to read/write to cloud storage.
3. Set appropriate config params in Spark config or whatever way you use to authenticate.

There are many guides available depending on your usecase, [here is one](https://deep.data.blog/2019/07/12/diy-apache-spark-and-adls-gen-2-support/), and [here is another](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/data/9781803231501/2/ch02lvl1sec09/reading-and-writing-data-from-adls-gen2-using-pyspark).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the pyspark reader/writer built-in methods?

It seems as easy as (I assume that spark session is declared somewhere in your code or that you use Databricks noteboks):

```
def convert_csv_to_parquet(
    input_file_path: str,
    output_file_path: str
    ):

    df = spark.read.format('csv').load(input_file_path)
    df.write.format('parquet').save(input_file_path)
    return 1
```

Comment: Thank you. It ran okay again but nothing in my output folder still. It takes almost no time to execute but nothing happens